# delphi masking time 00:00 to 24:00

Tags: delphi, time, components, edit

I'm using TcxTimeEdit component and customized to create CustomTimeEdit for my application in delphi.
However, I want to show 24:00 instead of 00:00 for my timeedit.
is there any way to mask? or cover 00:00 with 24:00?
I tried to utilize properties of tcxTimeEdit, but couldn't find anything that helps me.

Comment: Probably your best bet is to use a `TcxMaskEdit` with a regular expression for this. I doubt `TcxTimeEdit` allows it.

Comment: That's a pretty odd thing to do though. The user is going to be confused when you change the input so radically.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, if you have to select start time and end time of a day, is there logic in selecting 00:00 as end time instead of 24:00?

Comment: @LURD well, isn't that time tomorrow?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, day is already fixed. Entering 23:59 does not cut it since that will exclude last minute. Normally you check that the first time of day is less than the last time. Now you are forced to include another check. No big deal, but the I prefer to allow 24:00 as end time.

Comment: @LURD if it were me I wouldn't use one of these mask edits and I'd validate outside the control.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, yes that is what I do.

Comment: the reason why i was trying to put 24:00 instead of 00:00 is becasue I'm using the timeedit to get input for timeshifts. And it seems like it will be better for users to figure out the time when the shift gets over by showing them 24:00 instead of 00:00..... but i guess if there is no other way

Comment: You could use a normal TEdit component, or a TMaskEdit with EditMask `!90:00;0;_`. Then you would validate the input at a later point.

Comment: Midnight is commonly defined as `00:00` (hh:mm) and `24:00` is not defined at all in that context. A timespan `18:00` til `04:00` is valid but `04:00` represents the day after. Also the timespan is defined to be `from <= now < until`. If my shift starts at `08:00` and ends at `17:00` I can went home whenever it is `17:00` or past but not **before** `17:00`. So `24:00` has no sense to me at all.

Comment: @SirRufo, it is acceptable to use 24:00 instead of 00:00. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock#Midnight_00:00_and_24:00. It is also defined for use in [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock#Midnight_00:00_and_24:00).

Comment: @LURD it is allowed *Where convenient* ... sometimes I don't like that convenience at all ... anyway :o)

Comment: A time edit is not appropriate for a time span